# Can a complex differential equation of the second order exhibit chaotic behavior?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

From [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#cite_note-Rosario_2006-46) follows, that second order differential equations of one variable cannot exhibit chaotic behavior. Does anyone know if the theorem holds for a complex differential equation of the type
$$
\ddot{z}=f(\dot{z},z),
$$
where $z(t)\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is a holomorphic function? Are all such equations non-chaotic?

Comment: It doesn't look like what I need. The system in the post is 4-dimensional, which means it can be chaotic in principle. Having the restriction of f being holomorphic makes it difficult to find a chaotic system though.